# Total number of likes from list

Tags: java, vaadin, instagram

I have the following piece of code that gives the following output.

I wanted to know if there was any way to get the **TOTAL** number of likes instead of just individual likes.

Using: jInstagram and Vaadin

Thanks!

Code:

```
    MediaFeed mediaFeed = instagram.getRecentMediaFeed(userID); //Get recent images
    List<MediaFeedData> mediafeed = mediaFeed.getData(); // Store info from mediaFeed into this list

    for (MediaFeedData mediaData : mediafeed) { //For loop


    int likes = mediaData.getLikes().getCount(); //Number of likes for each picture
    System.out.println("Likes: " + likes); //Print likes
```

Output:

```
Likes: 1
Likes: 0
Likes: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int totalLikes = 0;
for (MediaFeedData mediaData : mediafeed) { //For loop
    totalLikes += mediaData.getLikes().getCount();
}
System.out.println("Likes: " + totalLikes); //Print likes
```